# iOS MDM: push not working

Tags: ios, mdm

I'm making MDM solution for my organization, and I have problem with push.

I have already setup MDM server, enroll MDM profile, create certificates, but when I try to push, APNS does not return anything and device does not connect to my server.

I use Apple docs and ruby code to setup server, [this](http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning) and [this](http://avibirnale.blogspot.com/2013/05/mdm-development-configuration-for-ios.html) articles for certificate generation, [houston](https://github.com/nomad/houston) for push.

I think problem is with certificates, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: how can we know without logs, codes, certificate details, etc?

Comment: I didn't get any logs, APNS does not return anything. For certificates I just do each step from articles above. Only one thing I change - replace in "houston" "aps" with "mdm" peyload

Comment: APNS should return message , if you implement `didRegisterForRemoteNotification` method.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor where I must implement this method?

Comment: In your App Delegate.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor can't find in docs anything about this. Can you share some links about it?

Comment: Did you read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: ?

Comment: No, because iOS MDM doesn't need extra app.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: kemootar is absolutely right. You are thinking about app push notifications, instead of MDM. MDM client is part of iOS system and dont' require any additional client side code.

Comment: Oops, my fault. I'd better read more about MDM

Comment: Were you able to build the MDM solution? Did you open source it by any chance? Did you use any custom ruby scripts or id you reuse the scripts that are shipped with osx lion server ?

Answer (score 0):

you can check the certificate and key doing this:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert certificate.pem -key key.pem
```

Also try this one:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert certificate.pem -key key.pem
```

You can find a good tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1).

Comment: I'm in the same boat.  Based on the tests, it looks like my certificates are valid.  Accessing the feedback service, I see that the token I got from the device is returned from the feedback service indicating that the token is invalid.  Of course this i the token I received from the device during MDM enrollment.  I'm now trying to figure out how to double check that the token or the push magic is correct.  @kemmotar, did you have any luck with this ?